# T-SQL: CHECK constraint not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, check-constraints

I have the following T-SQL schema. The problem I am having is that the check constraint on the `Download` table is not working. I am still able to insert records into that table that contain `NULL` values for both `ProductId` and `CategoryId`. Why is this so?

I want both the `ProductId` and `CategoryId` columns to allow `NULL` values, but for any given record only one of these are allowed to be set to `NULL`, the other needs to be a corresponding Id of the `Category` or `Product` table.

```
CREATE TABLE Category (
    Id int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Description nvarchar(100) NULL,
    ParentCategoryId int NULL
    CONSTRAINT fk_CategoryId_CategoryId FOREIGN KEY (Id) REFERENCES Category(Id)
)
GO

CREATE TABLE Product (
    Id int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Title nvarchar(100) NOT NULL,
    TagLine nvarchar(MAX) NOT NULL,
    Description nvarchar(MAX)NULL,
    CategoryId int NOT NULL,
    ImageUrl nvarchar(255) NULL,
    Keywords nvarchar(200) NOT NULL

    CONSTRAINT fk_ProductCategoryId_CategoryId FOREIGN KEY (CategoryId) REFERENCES Category(Id)
)
GO

CREATE TABLE Download (
    Id int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Title nvarchar(100) NOT NULL,
    Description nvarchar(MAX) NULL,
    CategoryId int NULL,
    ProductId int NULL,
    DownloadUrl nvarchar(255) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT fk_DownloadCategoryId FOREIGN KEY (CategoryId) REFERENCES Category(Id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_DownloadProductId FOREIGN KEY (ProductId) REFERENCES Product(Id),
    CONSTRAINT chk_ReferencesCategoryOrProduct CHECK (ProductID != NULL AND CategoryId != NULL)
)
GO
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use:

```
CONSTRAINT chk_ReferencesCategoryOrProduct CHECK (ProductID IS NOT NULL 
                                               OR CategoryId IS NOT NULL)
```

`NULL` isn't a value -- it's a placeholder for the lack of a value.  Which is why you need to use specific syntax to check for it.

Comment: Looking at my constraint I don't think it is quite right as now it fires every time I try to insert. What would be the correct way to write this to accomplish what I require.

Comment: @payntbrush: See update -- change the `AND` to an `OR` to allow one or the other to be null, but not both.